# CakePHP not autopopulating

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Data from `$this->EventoObreiro->find('all');`:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [EventoObreiro] => Array (
                    [id] => 1
                    [evento_id] => 2
                    [obreiro_id] => 5
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [EventoObreiro] => Array (
                    [id] => 2
                    [evento_id] => 2
                    [obreiro_id] => 3
                )
        )
)
```

HTML Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('EventoObreiro', array('url' => '/eventos/presenca/' . $evento['Evento']['id'])); ?>
    <?php if(count($obreiros) > 0) { ?>
        <?php foreach($obreiros as $k => $obreiro) { ?>
            <?php echo($obreiro['Usuario']['nome']); ?>
            <?php echo($this->Form->input('EventoObreiro.' . $k . '.obreiro_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $obreiro['Obreiro']['id']))); ?>
            <?php echo($this->Form->input('EventoObreiro.' . $k . '.evento_id', array('type' => 'radio', 'legend' => false, 'options' => array('1' => 'Sim', '0' => 'Não')))); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php echo $form->button('Salvar presença', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'button', 'name' => 'botaoAdicionar')); ?>
<?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

`$obreiros` are set from `$this->set('obreiros', $this->Obreiro->find('all'));`

But my form are not auto populated. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a number of things wrong with this, it is not clear from your code but look into the following:

1. Make sure that the information from `$this->EventoObreiro->find('all');` is actually sent to the view. You can do this using `<?php echo debug($obreiros); ?>`. If it is not sent you should verify your controller code [maybe even edit your post and add it for clarity.]
2. I don't see any **Usuario** in your Array so maybe try using `$obreiro['EventoObreiro']['key']` instead of `$obreiro['Usuario']['key']`

Comment: Seemed so, the associations should have been shown in the Array if recursive was set right. Good luck!